# GNOME- software not working

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-software

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 ( fully updated)
Whenever I search in gnome-software app, it shows "no apps found". Please anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Open a terminal. Show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

I think in ubuntu it is called as ubuntu software center, if you want gnome- software , then install gnome software using the command line.

sudo apt-get install gnome-software